# how to install different files for different platforms

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, command-line-tool

I'm building a command line tool using node/javascript, and want to make it available as an npm module. The tool requires a wrapping shell / windows batch script, but how do I install different scripts for different platforms? In package.json I have

```
"bin" : {
    "lookup-bat" : "./bin/lookup.bat", 
    "lookup-sh" : "./bin/lookup.sh"
}
```

but I would like to have the same command name, regardless of platform. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don t mind about that.

Usually, `./bin/lookup` is a js file starting with the appropriate shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

NPM does the rest.

If the program behavior needs to be different for the runtime OS, you shall implement a sort of `if(process.platform.match(/win/))` within your program.

Comment: The thing is, the node script isn't platform dependent, but the wrapper script is. The output of the node script is used by the wrapper script.

Comment: `but the wrapper script is` uh ? why would it be ? Whatever is doing that script, i believe you should do it with that cross platform tool : NodeJS

Comment: the wrapper script does 'cd <output of node script>' and cd can't be done inside the node script since it runs in a subshell.

Comment: mh mh mh mh maybe : )